# How to change / to \\ in the path to jvm.dll

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I thought which title to choose for 30 minutes, because my problem is rather strange.

Suppose we have a C++ native dll (**C.dll**). I want to load this dll with the help of JNA into my java project. Now what's important: in **C.dll** there is widely used a file path, from where this dll was called. And there is literally an if-statement like this:

```
if (filepath[2] != _T('\\'))
{ 
    //throw an arror and close dll loading
}
```

If I try to load this dll via JNA, it throws an internal dll error with the following message: "There is missing a certain sign '\' in: "C:/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-14.0.0.36-hotspot/bin/client" on position: 3"

I know the nature of that error and I also understand, that this if-statement is really silly, because it is absolutely anti-crossplatform, but I couldn't change **C.dll**, because it has come from 3rd party, well, you know that story.

What is also problematic - I couldn't just replace this file path parameter somewhere (f.e. via some other wrapper.dll or so), call then this wrapper via JNA and be happy, because all that file path checking inside **C.dll** is harcoded with the help of multiple macros and it is implied, that all the routines of receiveing and checking this file path are occured fully automatically (this is actually provided by other dlls, which **C.dll** have to use, and for which I don't have a source code, yes, it is **that** bad). So it is not so easy to find a concrete value which I could directly replace.

So, my question is: is it somehow possible to replace those (/) to double (\) backslashes in file path of jvm.dll in runtime or so? Is it possible to write a wrapper.dll, that will do it for my **C.dll**, either in C++ or java? I need to run this finally in JNA, that's actually why the file path is exactly JAVA_HOME or so - because as far as I understood java virtual machine is exactly the process, who loads **C.dll** in that situation, that's why I got the path to jvm.dll as a wrong file path. AFAIK all the java paths are harcoded with (/) in JDK, so from the JNA's side it is not directly possible in my opinion. But is it possible generally without changing original .dll? Maybe there exist something like path-replacers tools for java in Windows or so?

Comment: *but I couldn't change C.dll, because it has come from 3rd party* -- But you were able to see the source code to determine the error?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, correct, for this dll I have a .sol file, but it is prohibited to build a new version and change it on the working machines, because I will never receive a permission to do this from 3rd party. If I could -- I would just delete that idiotic if-statement and that's all.

Comment: Have you communicated this problem to the owners of the C.dll file?

Comment: Does changing the system property `file.separator` to the backslash help?  `System.setProperty("file.separator", "\\");`?

Comment: "AFAIK all the java paths are harcoded with (/) in JDK" ... actually they are hardcoded that way on systems except for Windows, where they are hardcoded with (\\).  How is it you are running on Windows and getting forward slashes?

Comment: @NomadMaker yes, sure, but we have very tense relationships with those owners...so I definetly prefer to solve it by myself.

Comment: @DanielWiddis thanks, Daniel, I've tried setting separator but it hasn"t helped. Actually I'm not an expert in all that jvm stuff, that's my I've only suggested, since I received such a problem. Maybe they are hardcoded with (/) inside jvm.dll, and then just corrected due to operating system in which java is used, however my **C.dll** wants probably to know from javaw.exe, what is the file path to the object, which will call my dll, and it receives "pure" paths, not corrected. I don't know that for sure, sorry, I am like an observer in that situation. Is there anything else worth to try?

Comment: Without knowing the exact sequence of code you're calling I'm not sure anyone can help further.  It sounds like the C DLL is fetching the path from somewhere, but you haven't posted the code for us to know whether a parameter is being passed that we can intercept via a wrapper, or something else.   I'm still confused how you are getting a forward slash on Windows to begin with.

Comment: I think you are right, Daniel. Unfortunately I cannot publish the code here, because it is too much of it and maybe it is also proprietary, not sure about this. So I probably close this question.
I'm also confused about forward slashes. Probably this is harcoded in java.exe, which called also jvm.dll in order to load a process. And setting up a separator is also not working.